# Errors when add class UITest target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xcode10

I have a simple weather app which gets data from OpenWeather API. I wanted to add UI tests to project. I added some classes to AppNameTests target in Target Memberships and after that I got many error in that class. But test is working and project build correctly and run without any problem. Is somebody know how to resolve this problem?

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: Can you add more details like a screenshot of the error and a screenshot of the file targets ?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa I added screenshot. there are another files with same errors, mainly CoreData entities and model files

Answer (score 0):

Your app's source code files should not be members of the unit test and UI test targets. To access your app's classes, structs, and functions in your tests, use the `@testable import` statement in your test classes.

```
@testable import AppName
```

Regarding Xcode showing a bunch of error messages when the project builds and the tests run without error, you can clean your build folder by choosing Product > Clean Build Folder, and see if that makes the error messages go away.